# How to add transition to multiple photos in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on slide maker. I want to make a slide show by picking some photos. I want to add transition in this slide show. Finally, I want to save this slide show as a video. HOW CAN I DO THIS?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve it :-

Add all the images in one scroll view.
Enable paging for that scroll view.
Based on the content offset of the scroll view highlight the appropriate dot(indicator in the bottom).

Or

[Kirualex](https://github.com/kirualex/KASlideShow)

Or

[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)